# Get data from server on android

Tags: android, server, http-post, httpclient, http-get

I use HttpPost to get data from server, But the received data gives me the error of not activating JavaScript, whats problem!

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

```
        try {
            
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("P",phon.getText().toString()));
            
        
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            
            
            
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                           is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            page_output = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return page_output;
    }
```

Comment: There is no enough information about your problem. Describe in details.

Comment: What do you mean "not activating JavaScript" what is the actual error and stack trace that you get. And what is the expected outcome